# Disconnecting quick connect fitting while hose is pressurized

Tags: tools, fitting, air-compressor

Tank is pressurized at 90psi. Attached to 50 feet 3/8 hose. Tool end of hose has a standard quick coupler. ( so its closed )

Is it "okay" to disconnect the male quick connect fitting from the tank? I understand the air in the hose is pressurized and air will come out, how bad can it be?

Comment: Grip the hose end very tight. With one hand while releasing the quick connection. Look away from hose during release to protect eyes or wear safety glasses. A loud burst of escaping air can startle others in proximity. Failure to secure the hose end will allow it to fly back from compressor very forcefully which could injure you or another person. I usually crimp off thehose close to end before disconnect and then gradually release pressure from hose

Comment: There should be a shut-off valve between the tank and the hose connection/coupler. If there is not, you should depressurize the tank completely and install a shut-off valve.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it  such a valve will not eliminate the pressure in the hose  unless there is also a bleeder valve in the mix

Comment: @Kris, I guess I thought it was evident without saying, to depressure the tank through the hose so that all would be depressured, then install valve. Thereafter, close valve at tank, depressure hose, disconnect.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it  depressurization of hose would be accomplished how?

Comment: @Kris, well if you have an air tank and an air hose, the presumption would be that you have *some sort of air tool or device at the end of the hose* that you could run the air out of, otherwise you would not need any of this stuff. Seems obvious enough to me to not need to explain, but whatever...

Answer (score 1):

The osha approved method would probably require depressurizing the hose prior to removing the male from the female disconnect. I do this at full pressure of 150 psi on my system all the time, I do use caution because the air shooting out the male fitting can contain rust or large dust particles. I grasp the male end in 1 hand and the female in the other, pressing in on the male end I slide the lock sleeve on the female and allow the male to start coming out but keep the fitting inside the female until depressurized this diffuses the blast of air and I have never been hit with rust or dust using this method.

Comment: I would agree that OSHA regs would probably require depressurization of the tank, but, you would do that by unscrewing the drain valve and that just lets the pressure fly out the bottom of the tank... That's a comment on the regs, not your answer! I separate tools & hoses with air in them all the time. Just have to hold on to the hose, as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

They make quick disconnects that will depressurize the line if you slide the collar back. This would be a good safe solution to the problem. I had gotten them from Kimball Midwest in the past.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more information on these products?